# Javascript cookie output

Tags: javascript, cookies, output

I can't seem to get the cookie output right. I want to type in a player name as a cookie, and get it printed out inside `<p id="playerName"></p>`. I know this isn't the best option, but its what I am going for atm.

**HTML**

```
<form name="myform" action="">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="customer" />
  <input type="button" value="Set Cookie" onclick="WriteCookie();" />
  <p id="playerName"></p>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function WriteCookie() {
  if (document.myform.customer.value == "") {
    alert("Du må taste inn et navn!");
    return;
  }
  cookievalue = escape(document.myform.customer.value) + ";";
  document.cookie = "name=" + cookievalue;
  document.getElementById("playerName").innerHTML = cookievalue("playerName");
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Error thrown in your browser console should be a good hint. ALways include errors when posting code questions also

Comment: 1. cookievalue("playerName") is not a function
2. escape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("playerName").innerHTML = cookievalue("playerName");
```

Use innerHTML to set the stuff in the tag.